# How does data source and delegate in UITableView works?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new in ios development. When I use UITableView, I implement data source and delegate together. like the following two methods:

```
 // Data source method
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

 // Delegate method
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

However, if I am understand correctly, table view does not hold any data, and it only store enough data to draw the rows that are currently visible. Therefore, for instance, if I have 10 data in table, and only shows 5 currently. That means delegate method runs 5 times, but before delegate method runs 5 times, data source method already runs 10 times to get the number of rows. And the reason we use data source is to manage the content that presents using a collection view. So my question is, how does data source manage the content? Does data source object store all of those table view information?(since it runs before delegate and it knows the total numbers of table view) If it stores information of table view, it seems conflict with delegate since table view delegate does not hold any data, right?

One more question is in what situation we just use data source? because we can create custom delegate right? Is there situation we only create custom data source? Since I've seen data source always comes with delegate.... Thanks!!!

Comment: I think you use term _data source method_ and _delegate method_ wrong. Both methods that you are talking about are part of _data source_ (`<UITableViewDataSource>`). Those two things are split: _data source_ provides data and _delegate_ provides behavior (reacts on events and so on). Usually both are implemented using _one_ class, so they are often mixed together.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `UITableViewDataSource` protocol defines the methods the `UITableView` needs to populate itself with data. It defines several optional methods but there are two that are required (not optional):

```
// this method is the one that creates and configures the cell that will be 
// displayed at the specified indexPath
– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: 

// this method tells the UITableView how many rows are present in the specified section
– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
```

Also, the following method is not required but is also a good idea to implement (part of the data source too)

```
// this method tells the UITableView how many sections the table view will have. It's a good idea to implement this method even if you just return 1
– numberOfSectionsInTableView:
```

Now, the method `–tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will run once for every **visible** cell in your `UITableView`. For example, if your data array has 10 elements but only 5 visible, `–tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will run 5 times. As the user scrolls upwards or downwards this method will be called again for each cell that becomes visible.

What you said: "(the) data source method already runs 10 times to get the number of rows." is not true. The data source method `–tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` does not run 10 times to get the number of rows. In fact this method only runs once. Also, this method runs before `–tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` because the table view needs to know how many rows it has to display.

Finally, the method `–numberOfSectionsInTableView:` runs also once and it runs before `–tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` because the table view needs to know how may sections will there be. Please note this method is not required. If you don't implement it the table view will assume there will only be **one** section.

Now we can focus our attention on the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol. This protocol defines methods that have to do with the actual interaction with the `UITableView`. For example, it defines methods to manage cell selection (when the user taps a cell, for example), cell editing (inserting, deleting, editing, etc), configure headers and footers (each section can have a header and a footer), etc. 
All the methods defined in `UITableViewDelegate` are optional. Actually you don't need to implement `UITableViewDelegate` at all to get the correct basic behavior of the table view, which is, to display cells.

Some of the most common methods of `UITableViewDelegate` are:

```
// If you want to modify the height of your cells, this is the method to implement
– tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

// In this method you specify what to do when a cell is selected (tapped)
– tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

// In this method you create and configure the view that will be used as header for
// a particular section
– tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:
```

- [Here is a good tutorial for Table Views](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/)
- [Here is the reference for UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)
- [Here is the reference for UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

datasource and delegate are two separate pieces to the Model-View-Controller paradigm. you do not need to connect a delegate unless you need/want to.

the delegate methods do not supply data for the table at all. the datasource has the actual data for the table (stored in an array or dict or whatever).

you seem to be confused because you list `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` as a delegate method, but it is in fact part of the data source protocol.