# How does UITableView work with UITableViewDataSource?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm new to Swift and I'm trying to understand how `tableView.dataSource = self` relates to the functions within the extension:

```swift
class ChatViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageTextfield: UITextField!

    var messages: [Message] = [
        Message(sender: "email", body: "Hey!" ),
        Message(sender: "email", body: "Hello!" ),
        Message(sender: "email", body: "What's up!" ),
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = K.appName
        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    @IBAction func sendPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }


    @IBAction func logOutPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        do {
          try Auth.auth().signOut()
            navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
          print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
        }
    }
}


extension ChatViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(section)
        return messages.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = messages[indexPath.row].body
        return cell
    }
}
```

`tableView.dataSource` is a variable from the storyboard, which is different from the two functions defined in the extension called `tableView`, which just happens to have the same name.  The variable `tableView` is being passed as the first argument to both of the functions `tableView` and not being used within the definition.

What is the relationship between the variable `tableView` and the function `tableView` and how the variable is being used in the function even though it's not in the definition of the function?  And what does `tableView.dataSource = self` do?

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501169/how-does-data-source-and-delegate-in-uitableview-works)

Comment: ok so `numberOfRowsInSection` has to do with rendering the entire table and `cellForRowAt` with each cell?  And the function `tableView` is the delegate of `UITableViewDataSource` protocol which is predefined by Apple?

Comment: When I look at this function `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)`, I see two parameters for the function, `tableView`, and `section`, none of which I had to provide.  Where do these parameters come from?

Comment: It seems like you need more explanation. I'll write an answer then... :)

Comment: Apple provides the `UITableView` object.  When it is being displayed, it calls the delegate methods you provide and supplies those parameters.  (You **might** have one data source that handles multiple table views and would therefore need to know which one is calling, but I've never chosen to do that...and probably never will.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many classes in `UIKit` uses this "data source" pattern to populate themselves with data. Other than `UITableView`, there's also `UICollectionView`, `UIPickerView` and `UIPageViewControllerDataSource`, just to name a few. What is said in this answer can also be applied to those classes too.

---

Instead of making you give it all the data all at once, `UITableView` asks for the data only when it needs. This is because sometimes the data could be, say, on the Internet, fetching them *all* at once could take a long time, couldn't it?

Okay, so who should the table view ask for the data? The `dataSource`! How does the table view know that its data source can answer its questions? By ensuring that the data source conforms to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol, which defines a bunch of methods.

Therefore, `tableView.dataSource = self` is saying:

> Hey `tableView`, if you want to ask for the data, just ask `self` (the `ChatViewController`)!

By implementing `UITableViewDataSource`, we are saying that this class *is able to provide answers to table view's questions*.

How do we actually provide the answers? By implementing the data source methods!

```
// this is asking:
// for section number "section" the table view "tableView", how many rows does it have?
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(section)
    return messages.count // we answer: it has as many rows as "messages.count"
}

// this is asking:
// for the row at the index path "indexPath", in the table view "tableView",
// what UITableViewCell should I display?
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = messages[indexPath.row].body
    return cell // we answer: you should display this cell!
}
```

Note that although the above two data source methods do indeed have the name `tableView`, it is more useful to refer to them as `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt`, and this is also what people often do.

Less importantly (for this question), in these methods, `tableView` refers to the parameter, not the property declared in your class. To refer to the property declared in your class, you need `self.tableView`.

The table view will call these methods whenever appropriate, also supplying the parameters. For example, `cellForRowAt` will be called when it needs to display a new cell.

A few misconceptions of yours that I spotted:

> `tableView.dataSource` is a variable from the storyboard

The `dataSource` *property* is declared in `UITableView`. You are merely able to see it in the storyboard (or more accurately, Xcode's Interface Builder). `dataSource` is not really "from" the storyboard.

> The variable `tableView` is being passed as the first argument to both of the functions `tableView` and not being used within the definition.

This `tableView` is the name of the parameter. You are not passing anything. Remember that you are *declaring* these methods, and you are not supposed to pass parameters. The caller - the table view - is.

Furthermore, you *are* using the `tableView` parameter in `cellForRowAt`, because the parameter hides the `tableView` property declared in `ChatViewController`.